# http - request entity too large - error 413

Tags: spring, rest, http

2015-02-24 15:38:23,255 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Comment: using restemplate.postFOrObject ()to pass a large xml in a GET request  . Is there a size limit that can be configured for resttemplate or should it be configured on the vfabric server. Is there a better way to handle such large data -

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the vFabric Server but all servers have limits on the GET request size. I believe that it can be configured. Also note that the client also have limits so please check the HTTPClient docs.

To answer your next question, you should use POST to handle that as its limits are higher but that again depends on the client and server. Note that these limits are there for a purpose (for instance: not to consume all available memory in case of a huge request) so you need to evaluate the functionality of the application and set them up in that context.

Comment: sorry that was a typo.it is a POST request

Comment: maxPostSize for tomcat. I think it should be the same for vFabric as well but not sure.

Comment: Yeah I did set that to 0. But I wanted  to see if there is any other way ,

Comment: Sorry but Like what way?

Comment: yes thanks. It did not resolve the issue for me though. I believe there are other network limits defined internally. Ill keep you posted. thanks